# Calling two subscribes separately in one angular function without mixing them

Tags: angular, api, post, updates

I am trying to call 2 subscribe request in one angular function, unfortunately only the first request is done

```
debugger;
            this.tableService.UpdateTableStatus(tableCode).subscribe(result => {
             this.statusUpdatedSuccessfully = result;
             if (this.statusUpdatedSuccessfully === true) {
               this.flag = true;
               alert('statusUpdatedSuccessfully');
             }
            });
   
           this.newOrder.employeeCode = this.employee.globalPassword;
           this.newOrder.orderTime = new Date();
           this.newOrder.restaurantTableCode = tableCode;
           this.newOrder.totalpayment = 0;
           this.orderService.addNewOrder(this.newOrder).subscribe(result => {
             // tslint:disable-next-line: no-debugger
             debugger;
             this.orderCode = result;
             this.tableToAdd.orderCode = this.orderCode;
             this.tableToAdd.tableCode = tableCode;
             this.orderService.listBusyTable.push(this.tableToAdd);
            });
           this.router.navigate(['/orders-in-process', tableCode]);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is because you're navigating away before it has a chance to go into the second `subscribe`.

A `subscribe` within a `subscribe` is an anti-pattern, so use a `switchMap` to switch to a new observable.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
debugger;
            this.tableService.UpdateTableStatus(tableCode).pipe(
              switchMap(result => {
                 this.statusUpdatedSuccessfully = result;
                 if (this.statusUpdatedSuccessfully === true) {
                    this.flag = true;
                   alert('statusUpdatedSuccessfully');
                }
               });
    
               this.newOrder.employeeCode = this.employee.globalPassword;
               this.newOrder.orderTime = new Date();
               this.newOrder.restaurantTableCode = tableCode;
               this.newOrder.totalpayment = 0;
               return this.orderService.addNewOrder(this.newOrder);
              })
            ).subscribe(result => {
             this.orderCode = result;
             this.tableToAdd.orderCode = this.orderCode;
             this.tableToAdd.tableCode = tableCode;
             this.orderService.listBusyTable.push(this.tableToAdd);
             // once the API call of addNewOrder is done and subsribed to here,
             // navigate away
             this.router.navigate(['/orders-in-process', tableCode]);
           });
           
         }
```

If you want to keep the `subscribe` within `subscribe`, you have to move the `router.navigate` line inside of the 2nd subscribe callback.